# Azure Front door caching VS Azure CDN for blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn, azure-front-door, azure-static-web-app

This is regarding usage of Azure Front Door caching and Azure CDN. I have a Azure static website that will displaying the data (mainly office files and videos) from Azure blob storage. The files in blob storage will rarely change. I am looking for the best way and cheapest way to cache these files, so that files can be fetched quickly.

Recommendation or supporting links will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The new Front Door Standard SKU is combining the classic CDN and Front Door. So the answer is: Front Door Standard is your tool to go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-overview

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Caching static website content is a technique to improve user experience as well as reducing the load on webservers by offloading the delivery of static content to a dedicated cache service.**

**Azure CDN**:

- Azure CDN is globally distributed network of servers that can deliver content to the customers in a very large scale.
- It is a **video streaming platform** where videos are delivered based on the customer’s nearest edge location.
- Azure CDNs stores cached content on the edge servers which results in minimizing network latency.

**Azure Front door**:

- It provides ***Scalable, secure and fast delivery of your global applications*** .
- It enables you to define, manage, and monitor the global routing for your web traffic.
- It provides best performance and instant global failover for **high availability.**

**Based on your scenario, that best caching you can use is Azure CDN due to the following:**

- Azure CDN is best for delivering **static content** like Videos, Images and PDFs whereas Azure Front Door is for delivering sites, services and APIs.
- Azure CDN is **cost-effective** whereas Azure Front Door charges per ruleset.
- Azure CDN does all the functionality similar to Azure Front Door.
- Azure CDN performs a good job at content delivery at a **cheaper price!**.

***Update: As suggested by @[silent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1537195/silent), you can also make use of [**Azure Front Door Standard**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-overview) which is a combination of classic CDN and Front Door.***

For more information, please **refer** below links:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-developer-community-blog/azure-on-the-cheap-azure-front-door-caching-vs-azure-cdn/ba-p/1372262

https://kishoregopalan.medium.com/azure-front-door-or-azure-cdn-what-solution-will-you-use-for-your-high-availability-sites-be26bb34aee7

https://walkingtree.tech/azure-front-door-azure-cdn-solution-will-choose/

Comment: all you write was correct I guess - until just recently Front Door Standard/Premium came out. This consolidates CDN and AFD (classic) into one offering. So the new answer should be: Use Front Door Standard, which is exactly what the OP is asking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-overview

Comment: Furthermore Azure Front Door even in classic mode is not expensive because it charges per rule set, the charge is much more complicated than just per ruleset, it also allows caching etc and WAF so its not about cost its about comparing the business need as well and per the new setups and SKU's as mentioned above its a much better solution to sue AFD

Comment: Seems that Microsoft have changed the pricing since last comments where made. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/frontdoor/#pricing, 

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cdn/#pricing
For static content delivery the cost is basically the same, but Front Door also have a "base fee" of $35/month for standard.
So cheapest option would be classic CDN .